# Algorithm/Code to compare gdb backtraces

Tags: gdb, crash-reports, backtrace

I need to find duplicates of a backtrace (I have in text form) in some kind of database. Ideally there should be a fast lookup method (hash based?) and a slower more acurate one.

I don't wan't a full blown crash reporting system, just the part that compares backtraces. But using code from such an (open source) system would make sense.

What I have found so far are only complex solutions:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport
- https://fedorahosted.org/abrt/wiki
- https://launchpad.net/bugzilla-traceparser
- https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/products/Firefox

Any suggestions how this could be done?

Comment: Recent GDB version (i.e. 7.4) are scriptable in Python. So perhaps you could make a script which also writes to a database...

Comment: My question is just about the comparing.